# Can not resolve int in onClick ( View view ) method

Tags: android

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

```
public class Pin extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn_pin;
    EditText input_pin;
    int Pin;

    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btn_pin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pin);
        int Pin = Integer.parseInt(input_pin.getText().toString());
        input_pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_pin);

        btn_pin.setOnClickListener(this);

        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_pin:
                int Pin = Integer.parseInt(input_pin.getText().toString());
                User user = new User(Pin);

                authenticate(user);
                break;
        }
    }
```

The line with `int Pin` has an error. I don't know how to fix this can help me?

Error:(42, 29) error: no suitable constructor found for User(int)
constructor User.User(String,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor User.User(String,String,int,int,String,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

its said Error:(41, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable Pin how i can find it and make it right.?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting at that line

Comment: I agree with @iagreen. Is that error a `NumberFormatExceptionError`? If so, then the string returned by `input_pin.getText().toString()` is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> btn_pin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pin);
> int Pin = Integer.parseInt(input_pin.getText().toString());
> input_pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_pin);
> ```

You should use `input_pin` after `findViewById`, or you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: It said the `User` class has no constructor `User(int) `, check the `User` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error:(42, 29) error: no suitable constructor found for User(int) constructor User.User(String,String) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor User.User(String,String,int,int,String,String) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

That means that you need to change your User when you want to use an int. And you declared

```
int Pin;
```

as a global variable. Then you have to use it in the rest of your source code without the type "int". For example:

Change

```
int Pin = Integer.parseInt(input_pin.getText().toString());
```

into

```
  Pin = Integer.parseInt(input_pin.getText().toString());
```